# Grep a line then print awk until a certain substring

Tags: linux, shell, awk, scripting

My code is

```
var=$(cat $FILE | grep "$alineimlookingfor" | awk '{print $1, $2, $4, $7, $9... all the way to $20}'
echo "$var"
```

But, I want to have $9-$20 be stopped when it hits a value like (0) or (1). This will make my output format and look a lot nicer because anything after (0) or (1) is garbage.

Does anyone have an idea on a way to implement that?

Input:

```
2013-02-21 00:12:03,374 [Thread] IN ProcedureTask - Finished Sales Summary 22 This (0) - 21-JUNE-10
```

Output:

```
2013-02-21 00:12:03,374 IN ProcedureTask - Finished Sales Summary 22 This (0)
```

EDIT: THANK YOU TO ALL THE PEOPLE THAT COMMENTED ON THIS THREAD ESPECIALLY ED AND GLENN

Comment: Provide sample of input and expected output.

Comment: Edited my post. Im trying to figure out a way to make it stop at (0) or (1) because the input can be varying length after $9 @anubhava

Comment: @anubhava I was thinking about searching for (0) in the line and incrementing a counter and then printing $i until that counter

Comment: Looping over the fields and printing them until a field of `(0)` or `(1)` is seen is a reasonable approach if that does what you want.

Comment: @EtanReisner Yeah the only problem I am trying to figure out is that (0) and (1) sometimes isnt on its own. For example from the above input This(0)

Comment: As an aside, you get not one but two [awards](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) for `cat foo | grep ick | awk '{ bar }'` when `awk '/ick/ { bar }' foo` would do the same thing in a single process.

Comment: The input above has `(0)` in its own field but if that's not always the case you can always match it within a field too.

Comment: @tripleee thanks for the info ill make sure not to do it again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update:

```
awk -v pattern="$alineimlookingfor" '
    $0 ~ pattern {
        rec = $1 OFS $2 OFS $4 OFS $7
        for (i=9; i<=NF; i++) {
            rec = rec OFS $i
            if ($i ~ /\([01]\)/) {
                break
            }
        }
        print rec
    }
' "$FILE"
```

Should meet your requirements exactly

Notes:

- `NF` is an awk variable containing the **N**umber of **F**ields in the current record.
- when we see a record that contains the pattern:

  - store the first 4 fields in a variable called `rec`, separated by the **O**utput **F**ield **S**eparator.
  - loop over the fields from 9 to the last, appending to the `rec` variable

    - when we see one that matches the regular expression (a zero or a one in parentheses), then we break out of the `for` loop
  - and print the accumulated `rec` string.

---

First of all, be aware that `awk` can do what `cat` and `grep` do, so we can simplify the pipeline immediately

```
awk -v pattern="$alineimlookingfor" '$0 ~ pattern {print $1, $2, $4, $7, $9... all the way to $20}' "$FILE"
```

Next, it sounds like you want to

```
awk -v pattern="$alineimlookingfor" '
    $0 ~ pattern {
        for (i=9; i<NF; i++) {
            if ($i == "(0)" || $i == "(1)") {
                NF = i
                break
            }
        }
        print
    }
' "$FILE"
```

This changes the "number of fields in this record" variable, so that subsequent fields are ignored.

Testing

```
alineimlookingfor=ProcedureTask
awk -v pattern="$alineimlookingfor" '
    $0 ~ pattern {
        for (i=9; i<NF; i++) {
            if ($i == "(0)" || $i == "(1)") {
                NF = i
                break
            }
        }
        print
    }
' <<'END'
foo
2013-02-21 00:12:03,374 [Thread] IN ProcedureTask - Finished Sales Summary 22 This (0) - 21-JUNE-10    
bar
2013-02-21 00:12:03,374 [Thread] IN ProcedureTask - Finished Sales Summary 22 This (1) - 21-JUNE-10    
baz
2013-02-21 00:12:03,374 [Thread] IN ProcedureTask - Finished Sales Summary 22 This (2) - 21-JUNE-10    
END
```

Outputs

```
2013-02-21 00:12:03,374 [Thread] IN ProcedureTask - Finished Sales Summary 22 This (0)
2013-02-21 00:12:03,374 [Thread] IN ProcedureTask - Finished Sales Summary 22 This (1)
2013-02-21 00:12:03,374 [Thread] IN ProcedureTask - Finished Sales Summary 22 This (2) - 21-JUNE-10
```

Comment: I did use a regex, but decided it was more readable to use strings.

Comment: What does NF stand for?

Comment: @EdMorton Oh so it only works on certain versions of awk?

Comment: What happened to his answer?

Comment: The updated answer worked perfectly. Can you please try to explain it to me because I like knowing for future reference.